# index.js exports are not working in a .jsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing, import, vite

I'm a very beginner in React. I created this React app with multiple components using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) from a [JSMastery tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tS7upsfuxmo)
And I used a index.js file in my "sections" and my "asset/icons" folders to import everything in one line in other files
But it does not work!
There are no errors or anything but my page turns blank (basically the empty "index.html" file)
I sort of fixed importing my section folder by importing them individually however i still have problem with my icons

here is "sections/index.js"

```
import arrowRight from './arrow-right.svg'
import chevronLeft from './chevron-left.svg'
import cheveronRight from './chevron-right.svg'
import copyrightSign from './copyright-sign.svg'
import facebook from './facebook.svg'
import hamburger from './hamburger.svg'
import instagram from './instagram.svg'
import support from './support.svg'
import shieldTick from './shield-tick.svg'
import star from './star.svg'
import truckFast from './truck-fast.svg'
import twitter from './twitter.svg'

export {
    arrowRight,
    cheveronRight,
    chevronLeft,
    copyrightSign,
    facebook,
    hamburger,
    instagram,
    support,
    shieldTick,
    star,
    truckFast,
    twitter
}
```

and here is how i imported them in my .jsx file

```
import arrowRight from "../assets/icons";
```

and this is my "index.html" file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./public/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Nike</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I didn't find any solutions online

Comment: Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try to create a minimal runnable demo project, such as on `codesanbbox`

Comment: `.jsx` files must be converted to `.js` files before it can be running in the browser env. 
You should use a build tool, such as `webapck`, `vite`, and so on.

Comment: Please, mark my answer as correct. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import functions which were exported not as default in that way (with curly braces):

```
import { arrowRight } from "../assets/icons";
```

Your export method is called *named export*.